# LibGDX - perspective camera smooth translation & direction

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0, perspectivecamera

I am trying to implement smooth 3D camera in my game. So, I have a few reserved positions and directions and I want to change view of my camera by applying them to my camera. Now I am doing it like below:

```
//Reserved positions and directions

//View #1
Vector3 pos1 = new Vector3(0, 5, -10);
Vector3 dir1 = new Vector3(0, 0, 10);

//View #2
Vector3 pos2 = new Vector3(5, 2, 5);
Vector3 dir2 = new Vector3(-2, 2, 7);

//Applying view #2
camera.position.set(pos2);
camera.lookAt(dir2);
```

It works, but I need to do it smoothly. I've seen a [similar question for 2D camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227994/how-to-make-a-smooth-camera-follow-algorithm-libgdx), but it doesn't appropriate for me, because orthographic camera doesn't need direction and Z-axis.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to use method which is described for 2D camera. So, positioning works as needed, but I can't say the same about direction. Behaviour of direction is wrong. It rotates camera on Z-axis. Seems to me I have to update `Up` vector too.

```
float lerp = 0.01f;
Vector3 position = camera.position;
position.x += (pos2.x - position.x) * lerp;
position.y += (pos2.y - position.y) * lerp;
position.z += (pos2.z - position.z) * lerp;

Vector3 direction = camera.direction;
direction.x += (dir2.x - direction.x) * lerp;
direction.y += (dir2.y - direction.y) * lerp;
direction.z += (dir2.z - direction.z) * lerp;

//CODE FROM LIBGDX'S CAMERA
//LookAt function
/*
tmpVec.set(x, y, z).sub(position).nor();
    if (!tmpVec.isZero()) {
        float dot = tmpVec.dot(up); // up and direction must ALWAYS be orthonormal vectors
        if (Math.abs(dot - 1) < 0.000000001f) {
            // Collinear
            up.set(direction).scl(-1);
        } else if (Math.abs(dot + 1) < 0.000000001f) {
            // Collinear opposite
            up.set(direction);
        }
        direction.set(tmpVec);
        normalizeUp();
    }
*/
```

What is the correct way to set direction?

Comment: maybe this can help you http://php-c.org/fletcher/2015/04/05/java-libgdx-camera-smooth-translation/ and this https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interpolation

Comment: @AngelAngel, these links are helpful for orthographic camera only.

Comment: @Nolesh why should this work for Orthographic camera only? At least the `Interpolation` should be usable for `Vector3` to, so it can be used in your case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use the [Univesal Tween Engine](http://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/), which is a library for interpolating pretty much anything.

You'd have to write a Vector3Accessor class (which would be very simple), but then you'd have all sorts of controls and options for smooth movement. It has a very rich API and is used a lot for exactly this sort of thing.

I'd strongly recommend you put a little time into investigating it as an option -It'll give you a better result, and once you know it you'll find all sorts of other cool uses for it in your app.